# Нажатие клавиши enter в функции input

Tags: python, input, if, while

код:

```
while True:
    a = str(input("---> "))
    text = "hello"
    if a in text:
        print(text)
```

вывод из терминала:

```
---> 
hello
---> 
hello
---> 
hello
```

проблема в том что, когда я запрашиваю любой символ у пользователя через `input()`, но ввожу <kbd>Enter</kbd>, почему-то ввод <kbd>Enter</kbd> есть в слове `"hello"`.

Answer (score 4):

*Пустая строка* (результат нажатия только клавиша <kbd>Enter</kbd>) находится во *всякой* строке.
Потому вместо

```
if a in text:
```

примените

```
if а and а in text:
```

---

*Объяснение:*

Выражение

```
а and a in text
```

значит *«когда `а` непустая строка (т.е. не был нажат только клавиш <kbd>Enter</kbd>) и строка `а` находится в строке `text`».*

(Первое `a` в контексте команды `if` имеет значение `True` тогда и только тогда, когда строка `а` непустая — см. часть «Объекты, которые приравниваются к False» в [Используем объекты вместо True и False — truthy и falsy значения в Python](https://tproger.ru/translations/truthy-and-falsy-values-in-python/).

Например, эти объекты имеют значение `False`:

- пустой список: `[]`;
- пустой кортеж: `()`;
- пустой словарь: `{}`;
- пустое множество: `set()`;
- пустая строка: `""`;
- пустой диапазон: `range(0)`.)

---

*Примечание:*

Еще лучше будет вместо переменной `a` применить выражение `a.strip()`, чтобы программа работала хорошо тоже после ввода пробелов перед / за вводимым текстом — метод `.strip()` их все удалит:

```
if а.strip() and а.strip() in text:
```

или сразу сначала применить метод `.strip()`

```
while True:
    a = input("--->").strip()
    text = "hello"
    if a and a in list(text):
        print(text)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
while True:
    a = input("--->")
    text = "hello"
    if a in list(text):
        print(text)
```

решение в том, что нажатие клавиши enter вводит данный знак:

```
"" \
""
```

данная символы эквивалентны просто "", что в Python является обозначением типа данных, а именно строка

с помощью функции `list()` мы возвращаем список из строки

```
['h','e','l','l','o']
```

и string никак не может быть в list

Comment: Правильно будет проверять длину строки, иначе если делать как ВЫ, то не будет работать на ввод букв, например - 'he'
if len(a) > 0 and a in text:

Comment: @AnnaVeneko довольно странное рассуждение. Ну а если все-таки ввели что-то норм. например `hell`, как-же вы будете проверять есть ли строка в списку?